# How to enable SSL support using Apache + Fastcgi + Django?

Tags: django, apache, https, fastcgi, httpd.conf

I have written a Django App and I want to enable SSL(Https) support in my deployment. Currently my web application is properly served on port80. This is my setup

1. I am using Apache as my web server
2. FastCGI as reverse proxy to serve my web app

I launch my Django app using the following command

```
/usr/bin/python manage.py runfcgi daemonize=false method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8080
```

I edited the Apache httpd.conf file accordingly

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

    Alias /static /opt/tms/web3/static

    #For every request that *doesn't* start with "static", send it
    #to Django via fastcgi.  The address and port must match the
    #arguments that are later passed to Django.
    <LocationMatch "^/(?!static)">
        ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    Alias /static /opt/tms/web3/static

    #For every request that *doesn't* start with "static", send it
    #to Django via fastcgi.  The address and port must match the
    #arguments that are later passed to Django.
    <LocationMatch "^/(?!static)">
        ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </LocationMatch>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/web_error_log
    LogFormat combined
    CustomLog /var/log/web_access_log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile       /var/opt/tms/web/conf/webserver.cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile    /var/opt/tms/web/conf/webserver.priv.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /var/opt/tms/web/conf/webserver_chain.cert.pem
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:-aNULL:-kKRB5:-MD5

    FileETag None
</VirtualHost>
```

and I get this error when I access with https

```
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with 
the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Comment: Can you post Apache's error log?